# How to count number of sub strings inside string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am trying to read a text file and count the number of times a certain string appears. This is what I have so far:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Test\\Documents\\Sample.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);

    counter = Regex.Matches(line, "the", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
}

Console.WriteLine(counter);

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

So I want to find all the words that contain the string "the" in them but I do not get the correct count. I want it to also count the "the" in like the word "withered" and etc and not just the word "the". The problem I found is that when the txt file contains different paragraphs and spaces between them, it misses of the words. When I put no space between paragraphs it seems to work. What can I possibly do to fix this?

This is what I mean by paragraph spaces:

```
Sample text Sample text  Sample text  Sample text Sample text.

Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text .
```

But if I combine them like this it works:

```
Sample text Sample text  Sample text  Sample text Sample text.Sample text Sample text  Sample text  Sample text Sample text.
```

Comment: each loop is going to set the count. you want to increment the count. `counter += ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the count for each line means you must move the `Console.WriteLine(counter);` to the bounds of while.

```
string searchStr= "the";
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter = Regex.Matches(line,searchStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Count of {0} in this line is {1}",searchStr,counter);
}
```

or else you can display the complete count of the search word if you update the `counter` in each iterations of the while.

```
string searchStr= "the";
 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(line);
     counter += Regex.Matches(line, searchStr , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Occurance of {0} in this document is {1}",searchStr,counter);
```

**Updates:** To get all words that contains the specific words and count the total number of occurrence of the search string in the given content you can make use of a List
 like the following:

```
 string searchStr= "the";
 List<string> totalMatchStrings = new List<string>();
 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     totalMatchStrings.AddRange(lineInput.Split(' ').Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(searchString)));         
 }
 string matchingWords = String.Join(",", totalMatchStrings.Distinct());
 Console.WriteLine("Occurance of {0} in this document is {1}",searchStr,totalMatchStrings.Count);
 Console.WriteLine("matching words are : {0}",matchingWords );
```

Comment: How can I save all those string that have the word "the" in it to an array?

Comment: What you meant by string here? is it that particular line?

Comment: I want to save all those words that have "the" in it. For example, the word "there" has "the" in it so I want to save that into an array.

Comment: @V.M Same as Akshey Bhat's answer: I don't think that this regex will be sufficient. If a single word contains _the_ two times it will becounted two times. Maybe [\b.*?the.*?\b](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb.*%3fthe.*%3f%5cb&i=hello%0d%0ahethello%0d%0ahethelthelo) is  a regex that may work. Using this regex a match will contain the whole word. `Regex.Matches(...).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()` will give you a list of all words containing _the_.

Comment: @Vera rind Sorry to asking many questions but how would I output the list? With a for loop?

Comment: @V.M Sorry I don't get the question. The answer contains a loop. Create an empty `List<string>` outside of this loop. Inside of this loop you do `list.AddRange(Regex.Matches(...).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value))`. After the loop you can output all the items with `list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`. Hope that helps. And yes of course you can write a for each loop and output each item.

Comment: @V.M: I have few updates for you in my post, please take a look. It will list the distinct matching words and print the count of occurrence of the search string

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment count instead of setting it everytime

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Test\\Documents\\Sample.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     Console.WriteLine(line);
     //increment count instead of setting it everytime
     counter += Regex.Matches(line, "the", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count; 
}
Console.WriteLine(counter);
file.Close();
// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't think that this regex will be sufficient. If a single word contains _the_ two times it will becounted two times. Maybe [\b.*?the.*?\b](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb.*%3fthe.*%3f%5cb&i=hello%0d%0ahethello%0d%0ahethelthelo) is  a regex that may work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\POC\input.txt");
var theCount = allLines.SelectMany(l => l.Split(' '))
        .Where(l => l.ToLower().Contains("the"))
        .Count();
```

Comment: @Verarind : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx
`ReadAllLines` method takes care of it.

Comment: Oh - yes. Missread the code. I read `ReadAllText`. Sorry - my fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can do this in a one-liner with LINQ:

```
int count = line.Count(f => f == 'the');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code inside the loop when read line by line and add count line by line.

```
Regex.Matches( Regex.Escape(input),  "the", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count
```